# What is multiply in recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am learning recursion and found code similar to this:

```
function repeat(operation, num) {

    if (num < 1) return console.log('eee')
    console.log(num)
    return operation() * repeat(operation, num - 1)
}

function operation(){
    console.log('lll')
}

repeat(operation, 5)
```

If I run I get this:

```
5
lll
4
lll
3
lll
2
lll
1
lll
eee
```

If I switch the last line like this:

```
return repeat(operation, num - 1) * operation()
```

I get this:

```
5
4
3
2
1
eee
lll
lll
lll
lll
lll
```

Why is that? What is multiply doing exactly there?

Comment: please add some input and wanted output.

Comment: Your initial code doesn't print what you describe it to print, you probably accidentally left a standalone `operation()` before return.

Comment: `console.log` returns `undefined` and not returning from a function won't yield a number.. it should be numbers in numbers out if you're going to be doing multiplication on its return value. basically `isNaN(NaN * NaN) === true`

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev yuu're right, I left extra operation(). fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, multiply is not used to multiply. It is used as a trick to change the order of function calls. Try replacing * with + and you will get the same result.

To demonstrate the concept:

```
function one(x){ console.log('one')}
function two(x){ console.log('two')}

one() * two() 
// gives:
// one
// two

two() * one()
// gives:
// two
// one
```

the result of both expressions is NaN

UPDATE:
The output represents the order of how functions are called. In the first case, `repeat()` gets called, calls `operation()` then `repeat()` again until num<1. This way you get alternating output.
In the second case, you call `repeat()` until num<1 then step out from the recursion and call `operation()` a number of times.

Comment: Oh I see, just a hack... Do you also know why in the second example first does 5 times repeat() than 5 times operation() instead of alternate?